# Another Fundamental Theorem of Calculus Proof

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, derivatives

Let $f : R \to R$ be continuous and $\delta > 0$. Define $g(t)=\int_{t-\delta}^{t+\delta}f(x)dx$ for all $t \in R$. Prove that $g$ is differentiable and compute $g'$.

I'm pretty sure you know that g is defined for all t because since f is continuous it will be integrable regardless of the lower and upper bound, but I'm not sure where to go from there. My original instinct was to use the definition of a derivative, but I'm not sure how to simplify it was you have it in the form of a limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the antiderivative of a continuous function is differentiable (The first part of the [FTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part) states this). Then 
$$g(t)=\int_{t-\delta}^{t+\delta}f(x)dx=F(t+\delta)-F(t-\delta)$$
where $F(t)$ is an antiderivative of $f(t)$. Then since $F(t)$ is differentiable, a sum of them is also differentiable, and hence $g(t)$ is differentiable. Then we have 
$$g'(t)=F'(t+\delta)-F'(t-\delta)=f(t+\delta)-f(t-\delta)$$

Comment: I actually had this written down, but for some reason I missed the part of the theorem that says the antiderivative of a continuous function is differentiable, even though it's quite obvious, so I wasn't sure if the next step was correct. I don't know why I'm over thinking all of these problems. Thanks for your help again man!

Comment: Want to try and help me with one last question? It would be much appreciated?

Comment: Sure, no problem

Comment: Assume $f : [a,b] \to R$ is continuous and $f(x) \ge 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$, and $M = sup\{f(x) : x \in [a,b]\}$. Show that $$\{[\int_a^b[f(x)]^n]^{1/n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$$ converges to $M$.


I'm not sure how to use the theorem when you have the function being raised to a power. Do you have to do something with a change or variables and look at it as a composition of two functions?

Comment: You meant this, right?
$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left[\int_a^b[f(x)]^n\right]^{1/n}$
Or do you mean just the limit of the sequence and not the sum?

Comment: Yeah it's just the limit of the sequence not the the sum.

Comment: *Now* you've stomped me. I've got nothing right now, but somebody else might be able to answer, or the answer'll come to me later, so I'd recommend you ask that question. Sorry man!

Comment: I just feel bad about asking so many questions in such a short period of time

Comment: It's okay! You're asking interesting questions (especially this one) and you're learning from it. It's no problem :)